# String concatenation acting crazy

Tags: python, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm trying to join each word from a .txt list to a string `eg{ 'word' + str(1) = 'word1' }`
with this code:

```
def function(item):
  for i in range(2):
    print item + str(i)

with open('dump/test.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    function(str(line))
```

I'll just use a txt file containing just two words ('this', 'that').
What I get is:

```
this
0
this
1
that0
that1
```

What I was expecting:

```
this0
this1
that0
that1
```

It works fine if I just use `function('this')` and `function('that')` but why doesn't it work with the txt input?

--- Edit:
Solved, thank you!
Problem was caused by

> newline characters in the strings received

Solution: see Answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
print item + str(i)
```

to

```
print item.rstrip() + str(i)
```

This will remove any newline characters in the strings received in `function`.

---

**A couple of other tips:**

1. A better way to print data is to use the `.format` method, e.g. in your case:

   ```
   print '{}{}'.format(item.strip(), i)
   ```

   This method is very flexible if you have a more complicated task.
2. All rows read from a file are strings - you don't have to call `str()` on them.

Comment: I'd be more specific and use `item.rstrip('\n')`.

Answer (score 3):

The first line read by python is `this\n` and when you append `0` and `1` to this you get `this\n0` and `this\n1`. Whereas in case in the second line you are not having a new line at the end of the file (inferring from what you are getting on printing). So appending is working fine for it.

For removing the `\n` from the right end of the string you should use `rstrip('\n')`

```
print (item.rstrip('\n') + str(i))
```

Comment: I'd be more specific and use `item.rstrip('\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first "This\n" is there that's why you are getting not formatted output. pass the argument after removing new line char.